# Custom BackButton in iOS webview

Tags: objective-c

I want to create custom back button on each page in my iOS web-view (objective-C). Can anyone please suggest me how to implement. 
Thanks in Advance
I am new to iOS Web-view that is why I posted directly what I want this is my code :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController{

    __weak IBOutlet UIImageView *logoImage;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad     {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.webView.delegate = self;

    NSString *urlString = @"https://www.anything.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];

    self.webView.hidden = YES;
    if ([_webView canGoBack]) {
        [_webView goBack];
    }}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    self.webView.hidden = NO;
    logoImage.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

I am passing a url of my website and I want to show a back button on every page of my application so that user can go to previous page. I have one more issue that whenever I minimise my application and opens it back from recent apps it get restarted while I want it to be resumed from the same screen

Answer (score 0):

For the `UIWebView`, check the method `- (void)goBack;` out.

For the `WKWebView`, check the method `- (WKNavigation *)goBack;` and `- (WKNavigation *)goBack:(id)sender;` out.

**UPDATE**

```
// init the back button
[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)backButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
     [self.webview goBack];
}
```

Assume you have set up your webview and back button (in the navigation bar or somewhere else) in the full code.

1. The browser could go back when the current (tab) page has a history list and the current page url is not the first ***and*** last one.
2. Make sure you really want to `goBack` in `viewDidLoad`, it needs some time to finishing loading the target page you specified (`https://www.anything.com`) just like you do it in a browser.
3. The method `loadRequest` of webview is asynchronous, it pushes the url request to webview and returns it immediately.
4. Bind the webview's `goBack` method to your custom back button like the above code snippets.
5. Try to click a sample link in the initial page (`https://www.anything.com`), once the new page finishes loading, it could be able to `goBack` with satisfying `[self.webview canGoBack]`.
6. Make a breakpoint in the implementation of method `backButtonTapped`, if needed.
7. Drop the `logoImage` or other unrelated code issues in your next question, that makes your question more clear and helpful.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer but please refer to my question again as I have edited it for more help.